# Update .htaccess to reduce length of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am sending a website live and I was getting a 500 internal Error.
So I have googled around and I have been able to find a solution.

I have added modifications to the code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue is that, when I enter an URL such as **www.app.com**, I obtain **www.app.com/public/index.php**

Is there a way to update the **.htaccess**  so that requests made to **www.app.com** will be redirected to **www.app.com/public/index.php** without showing **/public/index.php** in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (default location on most Linux distributions, yours may be different).

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` so you should have:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache with `systemctl restart apache2`.